# 3D scene graph in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, scenegraph

This is my 1st day of trying out libGDX after working with JOGL for nearly 6 months.

**Problem:**
I need a solution to bind 3D models to other models dynamically in run-time. I am designing a simple 3D dog fight game and the weapons in hard points need to be changed during game.

**What I tried:**
Coming from JOGL background, I thought using the Matrix stack to implement my own scene graph-libGDX do not have 3D scene graph. However, as libGDX depreciated OpenGL 1.0, I cannot find the push/pop matrix. Also, I know that I can apply transformation to the object via instance.transform, but cannot think of a way of implementing a scene graph with it.

Is there a built in in libGDX for this?

Comment: Nothing is built in. Nobody has ever found the time to add a scene3d implementation to LibGDX so far. The closest thing right now is probably https://github.com/pyros2097/Scene3d